# Notify when my question has been linked from another question

Tags: feature-request, notifications, linked-questions

Sometimes a question I ask will get answers that don't help me, or maybe it doesn't receive any answers at all.

How about making a notification when somebody links to my question?

It could be something like this:

> New information regarding your question might be available at {link}

It might help me getting an answer from related questions that weren't there when I first asked the question.

Comment: You could set up a [Google Alert](http://www.google.com/alerts) for the link search query, like `link:stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/`. One drawback is that Google also captures links from *Related* column. But maybe it's a feature more than a bug.