# Get notified when own post is linked to

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, notifications

My question is not a duplicate of [Notify when my question has been linked from another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236385/332957). The latter talks only about linked questions; my request is about both questions and answers.

---

I would appreciate to receive a notification when my own post (question or answer) is linked to in another post.
That way, I could see how my question or answer is relevant to other questions, possibly leave a comment in case the reference needs clarification/correction, or notice when a post I am the author of is discussed on meta.

It has actually happend to me several times that I accidentally encountered a post referencing something I wrote elsewhere and thought "I should have seen that earlier, then I could have added a comment to clarify what I actually meant" or "I should have seen this earlier, then I might have been able to write an aswer to or read about this interesting related question."

You already get notified whenever a comment is left under your post, so I think it would make sense to also get notified when a comment to your own post is left in another post.

If notifications are too pushy (but I don't think links to your posts happen so often it gets annyoing), a small section somehwere in the "activity" tab on my profile that I could check from time to time would do too.

Comment: I think you can do this with google notifications and the special *linkto:* syntax.

Comment: somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187682/notify-users-when-they-are-mentioned-on-meta

Answer (score 1):

This really doesn't give much benefit really, and the deluge of notices that might result would be very annoying and have quite a large window for abuse. Authors of canonical questions/answers such as [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/638824) would be prodded by notifications. (No, seriously, there are *thousands* of questions closed as duplicates of that!)

As to your alternative proposal, again, I think that authors of canonical questions/answers would find this useless, as it would require going through pages of notifications (or continuously checking) in the hopes that *maybe* one or two might actually require revising your answer or clarifying with a comment.

> notice when a post I am the author of is discussed on meta.

This might be a good idea. Maybe if a post is tagged with [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) or [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer), then the author of the first linked post of the right type is notified. Not entirely sure how feasible this is.

> You already get notified whenever a comment is left under your post, so I think it would make sense to also get notified when a comment to your own post is left in another post.

I'm not quite sure I follow your logic. If it's on another post, why should you be notified?

---

If you want a list of links to or from a question or answer, there is a list in the sidebar of questions pages.